# Copy Formula field into Number field

Tags: apex, trigger

Iam trying to copy the Amount from formula field into number field through trigger but it doesn't seems to be copying, i know i can do this through workflow but since this is an amount conversion for new exchange rates and if i do it through workflows i need to mass update everytime the currency changes, so i need simple trigger to copy the value, here is my trigger

```
trigger USDAmount on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {
 List<Opportunity > obj = [SELECT Id, USD_Amount__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN: Trigger.newMap.keySet()];
     for (Opportunity  o: obj) {

                  decimal amt = o.USD_Amount__c; 
                   o.Test_Amount__c = amt;  
      }
               update obj; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to do the update DML in a before trigger nor do you need to query for the records.

Other than that do some debugs to ensure the value is actually set

```
trigger USDAmount on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {

     for (Opportunity  o: trigger.new) {
                  system.debug(logginglevel.error,o.USD_Amount__c);
                   o.Test_Amount__c = o.USD_Amount__c;  
      }
}
```

Comment: Eric, Thanks for the reply, it works fine but once i change my exchange rate my formula field (USD_Amount__c) calculates fine but Test_Amount__c doesn't gets reflected with new value....is there any way to keep this field always in alignment with my formula field, like always keep the value same as formula field

Comment: Trigger DO NOT fire on update of a formula field......I would suggest running a batch process to process all records where the exchange rate had been modified and schedule it to run at an appropriate frequency